# how can i insert ( id ) url to database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

R : how can i insert ( id ) url to database Laravel

I have this **url** :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/question/1

I need to  save the **id** to database

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/question/{id}', 'questionController@choseType');
Route::post('/question/createone', 'questionController@storeData');
```

**Controller**

```php
    public function storeData(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'department_id'=>'required',
            'nameChoose.*'=>'required',
        ],[],[
            'name'=>'question',
            'department_id'=>'department name',
            'nameChoose'=>'nameChoose',
        ]);

        //here i want to save the id of this table to the question table 
        // which exist in URL
        $question_type = question_types::pluck('id')->first();

        $question = new questions();
        $question->name = $request->input("name");
        $question->department_id = $request->input("department_id");
        $question->question_type_id = $question_type;
        $question->save();

     }
```

any help pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.
I understood the function of `@storeData`, it will create a new question based on the request it receives.
As far as I understand, your `/question/{id}` route serves to "pick" the type of question before posting the question itself. The correct thing is you submit the question type along with the new question POST. In your Front, you must make a GET request, receiving all the available question types in your DB, and along with the requisition to create a new question, you send the type of question, previously chosen from the ones available in your DB.

**@Edit based in Question's Owner comment:**

If you edit your Route to this:

```php
Route::post('/question/createone/{id}', 'questionController@storeData');
```

In your controller you can do this:

```php
public function storeData(Request $request, $id) //the Id from the route
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'department_id'=>'required',
        'nameChoose.*'=>'required',
    ],[],[
        'name'=>'question',
        'department_id'=>'department name',
        'nameChoose'=>'nameChoose',
    ]);

    $question = new questions();
    $question->name = $request->input("name");
    $question->department_id = $request->input("department_id");
    $question->question_type_id = $id; //The id from the route
    $question->save();

}
```

Anyway, your route `/question/{id}` are isolated from the `storeData` function.

Comment: the question is : i have two tables one of them named ( question types ) the second named ( question ) and there is a column in the table ( question ) called question_type_id so, how can i save the id ( id of question types table )  which in url to the question table :: : hope to be clear now